# HighCharts show datetime format on xAxis

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

I am trying to display dateTime in day/weekly/month format on the x axis of high charts I have the data formatted as x utc date time format and y (magnitude). I was under the impression I only need to do this for it to work

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Chart with time'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: "%e. %b",
      month: "%b '%y",
      year: "%Y"
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      [1493326164493, 100],
      [1493326194018, 120]
    ]
  }]
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I have posted a fiddle link below for my scenario

https://jsfiddle.net/dLfv2sbd/

Answer (score 18):

[axis.dateTimeLabelFormats](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) works a little bit different. In the first place, Highcharts tries to guess what is 'the best unit' of your data and, e.g. if it is a day, it will format it according to day property from dateTimeLabelFormats.

If you want to just format axis labels, you can use [axis.labels.format](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.format) and specify a format like this:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    format: '{value:%Y-%b-%e}'
  },
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/dLfv2sbd/1/

Answer (score 7):

You can try format date with

```
 xAxis: {
   labels: {
    formatter: function(){

      return moment(new Date(this.value)).format('DD'); // example for moment.js date library

      //return this.value;
    },
},
```

Also you can check documentation http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: but wont this just format the label not the x axis value itself

Comment: Why you can't format your data before putting it in highchart?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also -

1. {value:%Y-%b-%e %l:%M %p }

> ```
> labels: {
>       format: '{value:%Y-%b-%e %l:%M %p }'
> },
> ```

Output- 2017-Apr-27 8:49 PM

2. format: '{value:%Y-%b-%e %l:%M}'

> ```
> labels: {
>           format: '{value:%Y-%b-%e %l:%M %p }'
> },
> ```

Output- 2017-Apr-27 8:49

3. format: '{value:%Y-%b-%e}'

> ```
>  labels: {
>               format: '{value:%Y-%b-%e}'
>  },
> ```

Output - 2017-Apr-27

4. format: '{value:%Y-%b-%e %H:%M}'

> ```
> labels: {
>       format: '{value:%Y-%b-%e %H:%M}'
> },
> ```

output 2017-Apr-27 20:49

Answer (score 0):

Simple year-month-day format:

```
 format: '{value:%Y-%m-%e}'
```